# Android Oreo 8.0 Emulator With Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I have the latest official emulator image of Android Oreo with Google Play. While creating (emulator) device, the sd-card, internal memory are non-editable. When the emulator starts, it notifies to use sd-card as internal/external storage but none of the options works and fails at formatting step.

It's not recognized by "adb" or in AndroidStudio. Cannot debug even after enabling from developer options.

It's play store is not getting updated, only shows downloading by Download Manager, nothing happens after that notification is gone.

The emulators with and without google play have different Google Settings> Security Screen-
Without Google Play(Left) -- With Google Play(Right)
[image]

[image]

My questions-

1. Is it possible to use it for debugging? If yes, How?
2. Why different Google Security setting in the two emulators with/without GP at Android o? Is it Google Play update issue or something else?
3. How to update the Google Play in emulator when its storage size cannot be increased (if it's the memory issue)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this problem is not related to Oreo image but other components of the system recently updated because older emulator images with Google Play have the same problem suddenly. Every image with Google Play have this problem.

Anyway I fixed it with clearing environment variables like ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_HOME.

I think the bug occurs when user files are not under user home folder (C:\users\ or ~username).

I had moved user files to my D: partition due to low disk space and this problem occured.

To solve the problem I set following env. vars:
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Android\sdk
ANDROID_AVD_HOME = D:\Android\avd

This way SDK and AVD files are under D:\Android and other user files including adbkey* are under user home folder.

Please have a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html#android_sdk_root to tailor your needs.

Comment: I have the same directory structure. I have already set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME and ANDROID_HOME correctly. How does it solve the problem?